# Wordpress Woocommerce Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, woocommerce

Hello I am developing an ecommerce , but I tried to do some loops and could not make it to work properly, should look like the image below , if anyone can help me it would be grateful .

btw: I'm using wordpress and woocommerce plugin in the latest version

I would like to stay that way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5HUC.jpg

Now is like the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XchOh.png